# Should I say "I don't must to do that" or "I must not to do that"?

Tags: modal-verbs, negation, complementation, bare-infinitives, to-infinitive

Which of the following forms of the sentence is the correct one?

CONTEXT: someone told me to sign on a document and I do not want to do that because it's only possible but it's not must.

> 1) "I **don't must** to do that"
>
> 2) "I **must not** to do that"

Comment: Second sentence is correct, but, it should be "I must not do that."

Comment: Note that *"I don't have to do that"* and *"I must not do that"* don't mean the same.

Comment: What are the different please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might say

> I'm not obligated to do that

or

> Must I do that ?

I think that's the correct form of these sentences.

Comment: This is the meaning that I looked for.

Comment: I'm not obligated or obliged?

Answer (score 3):

To me (a non-native user) the second sentence in the form *I must not do that* sounds correct, the first version is incorrect.

But I want you to clarify what you want to say.

- If you want to negate an obligation to do something, then you should say *I don't have to do that* or *I don't need to do that*. The meaning is then that you are not required to do something, but you may, if you wish.
- If you want to say that you are prohibited from doing something, then you use the phrase *I must not do that*.

In other words, the construction *must not* still expresses an obligation. The *not* negates the action replacing it with an obligation not to act. The *not* **does not** void the obligation, but rather replaces it with the opposite one.

Eagerly awaiting those who know the relevant grammatical terminology to improve upon this.

Answer (score 1):

You should say -

> I ***must not*** *<del>to</del> do* that.

The [*modal verbs*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/must_1?q=must) don't take `to + verb` format.

Answer (score 1):

The modal verb "must" is followed by an infinitive without to. So you cannot say ....must to do.  Besides, you don't put an auxiliary/helping verb before "must".  So both the sentences presented are grammatically incorrect. The correct sentence is as follows:

I must not do that.